# FCM Diagnostics Invalid Message ID?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using GCM to send push messages to multiple users, but even though I am getting success and message IDs in the response, I cannot debug them in FCM diagnostics and they don't arrive to the devices.

How can I debug this?

The message I'm sending:

```
{
"priority": "normal",
"time_to_live": 6000,
"delay_while_idle": true,
"content_available": true,
"notification": {
    "title": "Title",
    "text": "Text",
},
"data": {
    "title": "Title",
    "text": "Text",
},
"registration_ids": ["ID1", "ID2"]
}
```

The response is an array of message IDs.

Comment: Was it already working before or only for single push notification? Is the device not in idle state?

Comment: @AL. For me same issue now. Am getting the response of message ID but not getting notification in devices. It was working properly before. It stopped working since a month.

Comment: @Learning Hi. Do post in a question with the details along with some of the steps you tried to fix the issue. :)

Comment: Looks to me like that FCM query console is just broken - it does not recognise my message ID values that I get back when sending to FCM.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier it was my conclusion as well, that sometimes it doesn't recognise message ID's.